# Symfony 2, return true for bad roles

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, roles

```
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER: [ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_CHAT]
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

My view returns:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Role {#333 ▼
    -role: "ROLE_CHAT"
  }
  1 => Role {#334 ▼
    -role: "ROLE_USER"
  }
]
You  cant't see this.
```

My view:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Client panel</h1>
    {{ dump(app.security.token.roles) }}


{% if is_granted('ROLE_CLIENT') %} You can't see this. {% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

I don't know why is granted return true for ROLE_CLIENT, if the user has not this role. He has only ROLE_USER, AND ROLE_CHAT.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

In your Roles' hierarchy you can see that `ROLE_USER` is already have roles `ROLE_CLIENT` and `ROLE_CHAT`. This is the expected behaviour.

If you want it to return false just change your `role_hierarchy` block in `security.yml`.

Comment: I agree with @Michael Sivolobov